# How to send a push notification to a user that is in my database using FCM? android

Tags: php, android, notifications

For example, I need to send a notification to a particular user. When the user sends me a trouble-message, I will push a notification which notifies him that the trouble will be fix soon.

Now, I have already created a push notification but even when the user is logged out it can still receive a notification. And when I'm using a different account it can still receive the same notification for the other user.

please help me create a push notification that will send to a specific-signed-in-user. Thank you. (Sorry I'm new here in android.) thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send to a specific user, you can only send to specific devices. Your server/app needs to handle the logic of users and keys associated with them

Comment: What if the user has logged out? Do you know how to prevent the push notification and wait till the user is logged in ?

Comment: have the app tell your server to remove the key from your database